# Value Not Included When Mapping in AutoMapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have an action like following:

```
public JsonResult Update(UpdateUserViewModel updateUser)
{
    try
    {
        var existUser = _uow.Users.GetById(updateUser.UserId);

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<UpdateUserViewModel,User>();
        var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<User>(updateUser);

        _uow.Users.UpdateEntity(model);
        _uow.Save();

        return Json(new { Result = "OK" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

`UpdateUserViewModel` does not have a `Password` property but `User` does and it is being filled in `existUser`. The resultant `model` includes `Password` property but not the value that was in `existUser`.

I do not what I am doing wrong. Please point me to right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you map with

```
var model = Mapper.Map<User>(updateUser);
```

Then new instance of destination `User` object is created and populated with data from `updateUser`. You should map from source object to existing object instead:

```
var existUser = _uow.Users.GetById(updateUser.UserId);
var model = Mapper.Map(updateUser, existUser);
// you even don't need model here
// just call Mapper.Map(updateUser, existUser) and use existUser
```

Thus `AutoMapper` will use existing instance of `User` and it will update it with data from `UpdateUserViewModel`.

NOTE: It's better to create mappings once on application startup.

Comment: Downvoter, can you explain reason of downvote? If there is something wrong with this solution, I would be thankful to hear comments

Comment: @Downvoter Exactly correct answer, I see no reason for a downvote.